# How to save a file with a column with a value at the end

Tags: r

I need to save a dataset and adding a constant value at the end, for example add the value "202109" in 1 column.

Im using this to save:

```
write.csv(BBDD,"Directory.txt",row.names=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

After your write.csv, use:

```
write.table("202109", "Directory.txt", append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `bind_rows`

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
BBDD <- bind_rows(BBDD, tibble(!!names(BBDD)[1] := 202109))
```

and now we use the `write.csv`

#### data

```
BBDD <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 6:10)
```